# Shared volume inconsistently visible

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile I've created and I want to start it up with the local directory as a shared volume. I've tagged the image `foo`.

I can list the contents of a directory `test/` that exists in the local director when I run:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/.:/usr/local/src/spark foo /bin/bash -c "ls test"

# functions as expected, lists files in test/ directory
```

But, when I put the above command into a Makefile, I do not get the same results. Instead, when I run `$ make foo`, the following is emitted:

```
docker run -it -v /.:/usr/local/src/spark foo /bin/bash -c "ls test"
ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions on how to get `make foo` to "see" the test directory as expected when sharing the local directory in the `make` command as when `docker` is called directly in line?

Comment: Try with `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)`.

Comment: Or in a Makefile context, `$$PWD`; you need it to not interpret it as a Make function/variable.

Comment: Thanks both of you! @DavidMaze if you want to make your comment an answer - that worked for me and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Make rule

```
container-ls:
        docker run -it -v $(pwd)/.:/usr/local/src/spark foo ls test
```

Make sees the `$(pwd)` and interprets it as a Make variable or a Make-internal function.  You have a couple of options to work around this:

- Use a double dollar sign to escape it `$$(pwd)`
- Use backticks, which Make doesn't interpret as special `pwd`
- Use the GNU Make [realpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) function to get a canonical path `$(realpath .)`